# Tesla’s AC motor: questions on operation

Tags: motor, transformer, electromagnetism, magnetic-flux

The [Tesla Patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US381968A/en) for the AC motor claims a circular disk can be used in place of the rectangular piece of steel which rotates in the motor. The disc is more efficient. I can see how the rectangular steel piece aligns with the changing field but not the disc. **Why would this disc rotate in the field?  Why is the disc more efficient?**

In the patent Tesla says a disc of steel is rotated more efficiently then iron. It’s my understanding steel is a better conductor of the magnetic field. **Is this why he claims steel results in better efficiencies then iron per the following quote?**

> a circular disk, as indicated by dotted lines, is also set in rotation. This phenomenon attribute to a certain inertia or resistance inherent in the metal to the rapid shifting of the lines of force through the same, which results in a continuous tangential pull upon the disk, causing its rotation. This seems to be confirmed by the fact that a circular disk of steel is more effectively rotated than one of soft iron, for thereason that the former is assumed to possess a greater resistance to the shifting of the magnetic lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Why would this disc rotate in the field? Why is the disc more efficient?

The key here is to stop thinking about the motor as “pulling” the rotor using magnetic attraction - in fact an aluminum rotor would also work in this situation (but not as well, for other reasons).

An induction motor works by using the rate of change of the stator field to induce an opposing current in the rotor, effectively magnetizing it. Then we get to the exciting part:

\$\large\frac{d\text{ }sin(t)}{dt} = cos(t)\$

If one creates a rotating field on the stator (*ie.* the \$x\$ field is \$sin(t)\$ and the \$y\$ field is \$cos(t)\$) then the magnetic field induced in the rotor is exactly orthogonal to the stator field. These orthogonal fields product the output torque.

Why does this make the round rotor better? Better coupling to the stator, and no geometry that restricts the production of the induced currents.

As to the material selection, the two main variables for this design would be permeability and conductivity. Modern rotors use laminated steel to avoid induced currents and copper bars to maximize the magnitude and position of the induced currents (see “squirrel cage motor”)

Answer (score 1):

Iron is randomly oriented dipoles and can be very lossy in high BH fields.
Grain-oriented rolled steel laminates have the advantage of dipole alignment and the thinner layers between insulated Silicate coatings reduce eddy current losses.